# Require ajax request for route group

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I'm having a route group that looks following:

`web.php`

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'ajax'],
    function() {
        Route::post( 'checkTheName', function( Request $request ) {
            return response()->json( 'Something important' );
        } );
    }
);
```

Is this possible with Laravel to check whether incoming request is an AJAX request for all routes in a group (and if not, throw eg. a 404 status)? I find it kinda pointless checking it within every child route post. Thats why I would like to make a global check if request is within the route group scope.

Using Laravel 5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using middleware and using this to check if the request is an Ajax request or not.

You can create new middleware with `php artisan make:middleware AjaxMiddleware`.

Inside the handle function you might look to do something like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    abort_unless($request->ajax(), 404);
}
```

This takes advantage of the `abort_unless()` helper which takes a conditional statement as the first parameter and then the status code to return in the second. 
You may also choose to do `abort_unless($request->ajax(), 401)` which would be an unauthorised request.

You then just need to register the middleware in your `Kernel.php` file and either apply it in your route group or on your controller constructor.

Comment: Neat. Thanks a ton James. Unfortunately cannot upvote due to the 15 reputation barrier.

Comment: There you go ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this, is to return the `next` variable in every middleware handle. Above method with `abort_unless` will actually not work in Laravel 6. Have not tested on previous versions.

```
if(!$request->ajax()) {
    abort(404);
} else {
    return $next($request);
}
```

Even better is to return 401 instead of 404, since it probably is an unauthorized request.